# Can anyone see why I'm getting the error, {"ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized."}?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Been staring at this code for 2 hours and I can't find anything. It could be from fatigue. When I run the code, the errors points to

```
strSelect = "SELECT * FROM TGolfers where strFirstName like '%" &    
   cboGolfer.Text & "%' or strLastName like '%" & cboGolfer.Text & "%'"
cmdSelect = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSelect, m_conAdministrator)
drSourceTable = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader
Using dt As New DataTable()"
```

in the GetGolfer function Hopefully someone can help me figure out why I'm getting this error and fix it. Thanks

```
Public Class frmGolfer
    Private Sub frmGolfer_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    MyBase.Load
         GetGolfer()
    Try
        Dim strSelect As String = ""
        Dim cmdSelect As OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim drSourceTable As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
        Dim strSQL As String = "INSERT INTO TGolfers(strFirstName, strLastName, strEmail) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Email)"

        If OpenDatabaseConnectionSQLServer() = False Then
            MessageBox.Show(Me, "Database connection Error." & vbNewLine &
                                "The application will now close.",
                                Text + "Error",
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Me.Close()
        End If

        cboGolfer.BeginUpdate()

        strSelect = "Select intGolferID, strLastName FROM TGolfers"
        cmdSelect = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSelect, m_conAdministrator)
        drSourceTable = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader

        dt.Load(drSourceTable)
        cboGolfer.ValueMember = "intGolferID"
        cboGolfer.DisplayMember = "strLastName"
        cboGolfer.DataSource = dt

        cboGolfer.EndUpdate()
        drSourceTable.Close()
        CloseDatabaseConnection()

    Catch excError As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(excError.Message)
    End Try
    If cboGolfer.Items.Count > 0 Then cboGolfer.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub

Public Function GetGolfer()
    Dim strSelect As String = ""
    Dim cmdSelect As OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim drSourceTable As OleDb.OleDbDataReader

    strSelect = "SELECT * FROM TGolfers where strFirstName like '%" & cboGolfer.Text & "%' or strLastName like '%" & cboGolfer.Text & "%'"
    cmdSelect = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSelect, m_conAdministrator)
    drSourceTable = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader
    Using dt As New DataTable()

        DgvGolfer.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        DgvGolfer.DataSource = dt
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Where do you initialize the _m_conAdministrator_ connection? GetGolfer is called before any call to _OpenDatabaseConnectionSQLServer_

Comment: But probably this is a trivial error. A more serious one is present in your code. Do not use string concatenation to build an Sql Command. Use always a parameterized query. Search about _SQL Injection_ to know why

Comment: This is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: That is not the correct way to compose SQL and you should set `Option Strict On`.

Comment: I have that in a separate form called modDatabaseUtilities.

Comment: @Steve Im not sure what you mean. I know there are other errors, right now those are errors i can fix. Im worried about the one posted. That is where I am having trouble.

JoelCoehoorn I am not worried about hacks. This will not go live. im simply trying to learn.

Comment: If I guess correctly the variable _m_conAdministrator_ is your connection and it is created and opened in _OpenDatabaseConnectionSQLServer_ but this method is not called in GetGolfer but only after that call. So when your code runs the GetGolfer the connection is nothing and not opened. The command uses a variable without any info valid to reach the database

Comment: And if you want to look for an error caused by your string concatenation try to put in your cboGolfer.Text a golfer named "O'Brian"

Comment: Ah I see, what you mean. Thanks @Steve